# Zero of a function - Where did the factor (-7) go?

Tags: roots, maxima-minima

I am currently in preparations for a Math exam (BscIT) and came across some, to my current level at least, unsolvable problem.

The full function: $$f(x) = e^{-xn}(e^{-x}-7+10e^x)^n$$

The part that causes me headache is the following:

$$(e^{-x}-7+10e^x)^n = 0$$

I entered the equation into Wolfram Alpha, hit "Step by Step solution" and the output ... made me wonder...

[image: "Split into three equations"]

> The left hand side factors into a product with three terms
>
> $\color{red}{-7}+e^{-x}+10e^x => e^{-x}(2e^x-1)(5e^x-1)$

Where did the $-7$ go?
because this was the main issue holding me back while solving the whole mystery as regardless of how i changed everything around, i always ended up, having this horrible number somewhere, preventing me from getting a nice, simple and clean solution ...

Thanks in advance, X39

Comment: Seems you need to know how to multiply things...

Comment: Could you be so kind to explain to me where my exact issue is here? To my knowledge, the right part can indeed be written as $e^{-x}+10e^x$, however ... this lacks the `-7` :/

Comment: Yeah, I should then repeat that you need to know how to multiply things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** multiply out the RHS, keeping in mind that $(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$ and not $ac+bd$.

Comment: I think at this point ... i may really should just consider calling it a day and finally get to bed :facepalm: i just also realized what @WhatsUp was talking about a few seconds before i saw your post. Thanks